# TIBCO EMS 6 and WCF services

Tags: wcf, tibco-ems

has anybody already used TIBCO EMS v 6 together with .NET WCF Services and tcpBinding?

I am designing a new architecture and need to understand how well or bad is the WCF client performing. I was told that in older versions the WCF implementation was not so good so the best approach would have been to use SOAP and XML anyway instead of native WCF netTcp bindings.

Any idea? Thanks, Davide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the WCF stuff with TIBCO EMS v5, and ended up going with their "native" client libraries instead.

The main trouble I had is that TIBCO didn't provide a full implementation of a WCF binding - only some buildings blocks which you could use to construct a WCF custom binding from it. This just seemed like too much trouble and too much effort, just to get it to work.

The "native" TIBCO.EMS.dll works quite well and in my case provided a very simple, very easy to use interface to send messages to TIBCO EMS:

Comment: Thanks a lot for now, is this native dll usable as .NET client to put messages in the queue and to consume them afterwards from another .NET application? is serializing binary data or XML? what is the name of the transport channel? thanks again .)

Comment: @Davide Piras: see my own question about [TIBCO EMS WCF Client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312612/tibco-ems-net-client-wcf-channel) here on Stackoverflow. It is a native .NET client library which just stuffs data into an EMS queue. As for the other things - I'd have to send you the TIBCO EMS.NET developer's guide (a PDF) so you could have a look - it's been a while since I implemented that interface and I don't have the specific present at the front of my brain right now :-) If you can give me an e-mail .... (find my in my SO profile)